# android jni - NewObject function doesn't call to constructor?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I had build a simple example to call to java method from native code,
and I am calling to java method of some object but the constructor never invoke.

my java class :

```
public class MyJavaNumber
{
    private int num;

    public MyJavaNumber()
    {
        num = 7;
        Log.d("MyJavaNumber" , "con");
    }

    public int getNum() {
        Log.d("getNum" , "num = " + num);
        return num;
    }
}
```

cpp code :

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
        Java_nativeex_com_example_nativeex_MainActivity_getIntA(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
        Java_nativeex_com_example_nativeex_MainActivity_getIntA(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass localClass = env->FindClass("nativeex/com/example/nativeex/MyJavaNumber");
    javaClassRef = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(localClass);
    javaMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(javaClassRef, "getNum", "()I");
    jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
    return env->CallIntMethod(javaObjectRef, javaMethodRef);
}
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public native int getIntA();


static
{
    System.loadLibrary("ndktest");
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("onCreate", "" + getIntA());


}
```

}

the log output is :

```
07-13 14:00:01.049 6797-6797/nativeex.com.example.nativeex D/getNum: num = 0
07-13 14:00:01.049 6797-6797/nativeex.com.example.nativeex D/getNum: num = 0
07-13 14:00:01.049 6797-6797/nativeex.com.example.nativeex D/onCreate: 0
```

How it can be that I'm calling to methos on object but the constructor never invoke?

Answer (score 3):

```
javaMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(javaClassRef, "getNum", "()I");
jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
```

`javaMethodRef` is inacceptable, [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) says about `NewObject`:

> Constructs a new Java object. The method ID indicates which
>   constructor method to invoke. This ID must be obtained by calling
>   GetMethodID() with `<init>` as the method name and `void` (`V`) as the
>   return type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the param "obj" in method `Java_nativeex_com_example_nativeex_MainActivity_getIntA(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)`

This parameter is an object of MyJavaNumber. It was also confusing to me when the constructor was invoked.